# How can I achieve grid typesetting with a figure?

Tags: vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

One of the requirements of our publisher for the book to be published is grid typesetting. Of course I already had a look into how to use `\raggedbottom` and adjust all vertical lengths to achieve this. But there is one last thing where we need manual fiddling and I don't know where my error in thinking is.

So we have an image which originally is `W267.0mm x H100.5mm` and because we have `20mm` margins on `A4` paper, we scale the image to `\textwidth` and now have `W170.0mm x H63.99mm` or converted to Adobe Points `W481.89p x H 181.39bp`. My thinking is, that to achieve typesetting according to the grid. I find the next mutliple of `12bp` which is `192bp` and the difference is `10.61bp`. If I apply this space, the text below the image should follow the grid again. Everything put in code it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\setkomafont{caption}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10.61bp}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0bp}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=170mm,height=63.99mm]{example-image-A}
        \caption{Just a test}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

However I prepared a visual check of this page and used `LaTeX` for this as well, so I use the output of above and use it as `Registerhaltigkeit.pdf` for the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(\x+1)] in {1}{
\newpage
\begin{textblock*}{105mm}[0,0](0mm,0mm)%
    \noindent%
    \includegraphics[page=\x,trim=0mm 0mm 105mm 0mm,width=105mm,clip]{Registerhaltigkeit.pdf}%
\end{textblock*}%
\begin{textblock*}{105mm}[0,0](105mm,0mm)%
    \noindent%
    \includegraphics[page=\y,trim=105mm 0mm 0mm 0mm,width=105mm,clip]{Registerhaltigkeit.pdf}%
\end{textblock*}%
~
}
\end{document}
```

And the final result looks reveals that up to the figure everything is in register, thereafter there is an offset between the two pages:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, which numbers am I'm messing up or which internals skips do I miss? Thanks for your support as always.

---

**After comment of @barbara beeton**

The comment of @barbara beeton brought me to the point that I wanted to answer just use `article` instead of `scrartcl`, it doesn't change a thing, but this is not true. Using `scrbook` instead of `scrartcl` is not really changing something, but using `book` instead of `scrbook` does.

So here is my new code, which uses the standard `book` class and the `caption` package:

```
%\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=20mm,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

%\setkomafont{caption}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}
%\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{MyFont}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=MyFont,labelfont=MyFont}

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10.61bp}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0bp}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=170mm,height=63.99mm]{example-image-A}
        \caption{Just a test}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

And now applying the second script, my result looks like this:
[image]

So you can see that after the figure now everything is set on grid, which means my calculation was right. However now I have some more questions:

1. What extra spacing is added between the figure caption and the following text?
2. Why does it match the vertical distance or where is this space taken from so the lines are matching afterwards again?
3. What extra space is added by `KOMA-Script` that obviously messes up the vertical spacing?

Maybe you have some hints for me?

---

OK, I found a partial answer and here is an intermediate result, I will also post an answer in the next days:

[image]

Comment: This probably most demonstrates my ignorance, but what does "register accuracy" mean? I'm honestly not familiar with this term.

Comment: @Mico you speak German, right? As far as I found this is the translation of Registerhaltigkeit. Check Register (Druck) in the German Wikipedia. Do you have a better translation? In the end it means a line is on the same vertical height on every page.

Comment: +1. I do speak German :-) , but I am completely and utterly out of my depth on the subject raised by your posting. I read the wikipedia page you allude to, but I understood just about nothing. Aside: I also suspect that translating "Registerhaltigkeit" as "register accuracy" -- does that come from Google Translate? -- is not all that idiomatic from a point of view of typographers' jargon.

Comment: @Mico -- I suspect that what is desired is what is also known as "grid typesetting".  (But beyond hypothesizing what is meant, I'm out of my depth.)

Comment: @Mico: I checked linguee and they reference MAN Roland, Heidelberger and a Swiss printing machine manufacturer but it seems they are all wrong, because Barbara is right, I am looking for grid typesetting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for throwing in that name. Indeed I am looking for grid typesetting, so in my example the line from Figure 1 should be on the same vertical position as the „et lecture“ line.

Comment: There are quite a few postings on this site about grid typesetting. Hopefully, some of them will be useful to you. (I'm afraid I know next to nothing about grid typesetting.)

Comment: @Mico that‘s true and I think I am trying exactly what they are mentioning, which is making the graphic plus whitespace a multiple of the baseline. Do you or anyone spot my mistake where there is extra whitespace added by LaTeX or another caveat that I am overlooking?

Comment: @TobiBS -- I'm totally unfamiliar with `scrartcl` (my sandbox has been the AMS and default LaTeX classes), but wonder why you are using an article class for a book.  I know that `book` and `amsbook` don't adhere to a grid for the first page of a chapter, nor do they do so when (sub)section headings use a type size larger than the normal text size, although they can be made to do so with fairly reasonable modifications. If there is display math, all bets are off. It's mainly because TeX was designed to handle math gracefully that no effort was made in the design to conform to grid typesetting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your comment, I updated my question and would like to answer your questions as well. In my real example I am using `scrbook`, however for the MWE it didn't really matter. Also the formatting of chapter/section/other titles was already solved by myself, so I didn't want to complicate the MWE. The final book contains no single formula and only one figure, this is why I am fine with a manual solution. Next time I will just use ConTeXt which seems to be the grid typesetting goto place. But I can't for this project. ;-)

Comment: Grid  typesetting is problematic in LaTeX. I would start  with https://ctan.org/topic/typeset-grid and then with the question about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to make sure that your figure and the space surrounding it will stay within the grid. As you used a figure environment but with "h" I presume you want it within the text (but I hope you are aware that this can float away as "h" only means "h if it fits". The problem is that floating figures get spae only on one side while intext figures get space above and below (and possibly \lineskip because the figure is just a big box).

Your best bet I guess is to define your own environment that starts a figure env but then typesets the figure content inclduding caption into a named box you measure that end alter its dimensions to fit your grid requirements by adding extra space above and below and then \usebox{myadjustedbox} and then end the figure env. In addition you need to adjust the floating pararameters to be rigid and fitting to whatever you use as height steps.

Alternatively if you always explicitly place the figures inside the text you can just avoid using the figure env and instead use \captionof (from the float package) to get a caption. The you are free play with the spaces around your fake figure as you like.

I know that this isn't a finished recipe, but this is roughly what is needed.

A good helper is \showoutput to see what spaces get added where. The extra space added by caption depends on the class (or package) you use but it is often \abovecaptionskip. The float parameters to adjust are \intextsep, \floatsep, \textfloatsep, etc.